# What does SIMD mean?

Tags: gpu, cpu-architecture, simd

I have read from the book "Operating System Internals and Design Principles" written by "William Stallings" that GPUs are Single-Instruction on Multiple Data, I don't get it what it means. I searched in google and got this assumption which I am not sure if it is right or wrong and that is:

- SIMD GPU means the GPU processes only one instruction on an array of data, for example of a game, the GPU is only responsible for graphical representation of the game and the rest of calculation is being done by CPU, is it true.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD

Comment: https://www.techwalla.com/articles/differences-between-simd-and-mimd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/simd/info could use some more info beyond the thumbnail, so if anyone feels like answering this question, a canonical to link from the tag wiki might be useful.  But anyway, SIMD is not specific to GPUs at all.  Most high-performance CPU architectures have SIMD extensions too, like x86 SSE/SSE2 that allows one instruction to work with 128-bit registers as 4x `float`, 2x `double`, or any of 16x 8-bit integer, or 16/32/64-bit integer.

Comment: Most GPUs are SIMT these days anyways.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of GPU's, SIMD is a type of hardware architecture such that there are simultaneous (parallel) computations (Execution of an instruction), but only a single process (instruction) at a given moment.

Schematically, the SIMD architecture can be drawn as the following:

[image]

(credit for wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)

Data Pool in our context is the GPU memory & PU is a processing unit or execution unit (Cuda core in NVidia's GPU terms).
Bottom line - a single core of GPU can execute simultaneously the same instruction over different data.

Comment: That diagram looks like CPU short-vector SIMD.