# Applying rotation to group of nodes sometimes flip the nodes

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am trying to rotate a group of objects in the scene by applying Rotation to each node. The rotation part of the code is as simple as:

```
for node in sceneView.scene.rootNode.childNodes {
    node.localRotate(by: SCNVector4(0,1,0, Double.pi/180))
}
```

The expected result is the resulting node will rotate by 1 degree every time it is triggered. However, I have noticed sometimes the resulting image have reversed y values (for example, the rotation vector was -1 in the previous frame but the next frame it suddenly becomes +1), resulting in something looks like an illusion. The frequency looks like it happens every other frame or so. I tried with different axis but the same thing also occurs. I have tried both localRotate and Rotate, the problem still exists. Is this suppose to happen?

This is a video link for demonstrating the problem:
https://res.cloudinary.com/df7kpyhrg/video/upload/v1616634641/RPReplay_Final1616634008_ohvg1k.mp4

Answer (score 0):

I am still not 100% sure, but I think the problem was I need to use the simd version of the ar modification. I need to use simdRotate instead of rotate. I believe the current flip in the video is the change in the angel which will look like reflection. To give a clearer example, suppose the current angel is 0 and it increments in the scale of 0.1 radian, the values will be 0, -0.1, 0.1, -0.2, 0.2 and so on. Therefore the flip results are the intermediate results to be executed. This stack overflow posts explains the difference between simd and non-simd methods nicely
[What does SIMD mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226548/what-does-simd-mean)